# CKEditor5 plugins in TYPO3

Tags: npm, build, typo3, ckeditor

i use this converter for TYPO3 Plugins: [Github repo](https://github.com/Beronimus/Typo3-CKEditor5-Plugin-Converter)

If i change my webpack to build the code-block plugin like this:

```
entry: './node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'cke-code-block-plugin.js',
    library: {
        type: 'module',
    },
},
```

after i execute

```
npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block@38.1.0
```

i'll get this message with `npm run build`

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockcommand.js 64:27-32
export 'first' (imported as 'first') was not found in 'ckeditor5/src/utils' (possible exports: CKEditorError, Collection, FocusTracker, KeystrokeHandler, ObservableMixin)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockediting.js 11:0-50 72:45-61
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js 9:0-50 25:16-32

WARNING in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockcommand.js 79:27-32
export 'first' (imported as 'first') was not found in 'ckeditor5/src/utils' (possible exports: CKEditorError, Collection, FocusTracker, KeystrokeHandler, ObservableMixin)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockediting.js 11:0-50 72:45-61
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js 9:0-50 25:16-32

WARNING in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockediting.js 132:31-43
export 'UpcastWriter' (imported as 'UpcastWriter') was not found in 'ckeditor5/src/engine' (possible exports: addBackgroundRules, isLength, isPercentage)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js 9:0-50 25:16-32

WARNING in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockui.js 36:56-71
export 'SplitButtonView' (imported as 'SplitButtonView') was not found in 'ckeditor5/src/ui' (possible exports: ButtonView, ColorGridView, ColorPickerView, ColorTileView, FocusCycler, LabelView, Model, Template, View, ViewCollection, addListToDropdown, createDropdown, focusChildOnDropdownOpen, getLocalizedColorOptions, icons, normalizeColorOptions)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js 10:0-40 25:34-45

WARNING in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/utils.js 194:23-28
export 'first' (imported as 'first') was not found in 'ckeditor5/src/utils' (possible exports: CKEditorError, Collection, FocusTracker, KeystrokeHandler, ObservableMixin)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblockediting.js 14:0-132 70:40-84 134:27-63 227:29-50
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js 9:0-50 25:16-32
```

When i add `export const first = Utils.first` inside the `cke-translator-utils.js`
and the rest in the other files i can build the package without an error. After that i'll get this in TYPO3 and the editor won't load.

```
Uncaught (in promise) CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at cke-code-block-plugin.js?bust=5efc4e531294f9910d2d901eea9eb07ee9e3c8aa:2:13691
    at cke-code-block-plugin.js?bust=5efc4e531294f9910d2d901eea9eb07ee9e3c8aa:2:181280
```

How can i solve this issue?